# Change Hash Array keys to strings

Tags: ruby, arrays, algorithm, hash

I have this Hash:

```
{["word"]=>1, ["cat"]=>2, ["tree"]=>1, ["dog"]=>1}
```

But I want to have this Hash:

```
{"word"=>1, "cat"=>2, "tree"=>1, "dog"=>1}
```

I have made several attempts with `each_key` and `join` but nothing seems to work.

How do I do it?

Comment: Construct a new hash with correct keys.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Maybe you should figure out why your keys are being created as arrays? Odds are good you're doing something wrong when the hash is created, and now you're trying to clean up.

Comment: I am getting duplicates from a string:phrase = "the dog and the dog"

Comment: phrase = "The dog and the dog" h = Hash.new(0)
    phrase.each { |e| h[e] += 1 }
    return h

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another one:

```
hash = {["word"]=>1, ["cat"]=>2, ["tree"]=>1, ["dog"]=>1}

hash.map { |(k), v| [k, v] }.to_h
#=> {"word"=>1, "cat"=>2, "tree"=>1, "dog"=>1}
```

Comment: @BroiSatse that's Ruby's [array decomposition](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition) feature

Answer (score 1):

This does the trick.

```
h = {["word"]=>1, ["cat"]=>2, ["tree"]=>1, ["dog"]=>1}
h.keys.each { |k| h[k.first] = h.delete(k) }
```

h is now {"word"=>1, "cat"=>2, "tree"=>1, "dog"=>1}

Comment: Nice one, +1, but note that in the block, you can write directly `{ |k| h[k[0]] = h.delete k }`, as `Hash#delete` returns the value of the key being deleted.

Answer (score 0):

These kinds of situations arises so often with Ruby hashes, that I wrote methods to solve them in my `y_support` gem. First, type in the command line `gem install y_support`, and then:

```
require 'y_support/core_ext/hash'

h = { ["word"]=>1, ["cat"]=>2, ["tree"]=>1, ["dog"]=>1 }
h.with_keys &:first
#=> {"word"=>1, "cat"=>2, "tree"=>1, "dog"=>1}
```

Another way of writing the same would be

```
h.with_keys do |key| key[0] end
```

Other useful methods defined in `y_support` gem are `Hash#with_values`, `Hash#with_keys!`, `Hash#with_values!` (in-place modification versions), and `Hash#modify`, which "maps a hash to a hash" in the same way as `Array#map` maps an array to an array.